# babelHelpers.js throws Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I just updated to RN 0.27 from 0.24 and all these "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined" errors started to pop up. After some research I realized there was a breaking change in RN 0.26 so i changed my import statements as indicated in 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.25.1
and other StackOverflow posts on the subject. After changing all of my component classes I still see this:

[image]

The inherits function in babelHelpers.js is:

```
babelHelpers.inherits = function (subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function,not " + typeof superClass);
}
```

What is the problem with it? Looks like this is part of react-native library.

I know there is a transform available [here](https://github.com/sibelius/codemod-RN24-to-RN25) to fix the "import problem" in general. Has anyone run it successfully?

BTW - here are my dependencies currently used:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@remobile/react-native-splashscreen": "^1.0.3",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
  "react": "^15.1.0",
  "react-native": "^0.27.2",
  "react-native-navbar": "^1.5.0",
  "react-native-side-menu": "^0.18.1",
  "realm": "^0.13.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "^12.1.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
  "jest-cli": "^12.1.1",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0"
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was with one of the add on packages. When I looked down the stack there is a reference to class monthSelector.js and in it on line 20 there is reference to react-native-side-menu add-on package.
When I looked in their index.js - sure enough it was importing Component from react-native instead of react.
Their new version 0.19 has this problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that in `index.android.js` I was using a component class to derive `AndroidApp` from which didn't exist (anymore). The error was a result of the `superClass` argument passed to `babelHelpers.inherits()` being `undefined`.

The error message isn't really that helpful because the `inherits()` function only checks if `superClass` is not null. It would be nice if it checked for `undefined` too.